# Is it possible to merge WPF solution which uses native binaries libraries into one exe file?

Tags: .net, wpf, merge, exe

I want to merge WPF solution into one exe file. This solution has native libraries dependencies.
I have found a couple of workarounds for WPF but they don't work for my case.

- add dlls to project as embedded resources http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx - not good enough because I don't want to think about adding any new dll as a resource, want an automated process.
- the way to do the same thing automatically - http://www.paulrohde.com/merging-a-wpf-application-into-a-single-exe/ - is better but doesn't support native binaries.

And one more point - native binaries have two dll versions (amd64, x86).

Don't want to use any paid solutions. Want to create some automated process for this.